# Zend 2 Multiple Navigation Partials - Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, zend-framework2

I am trying to set up the left/right main navigation with bootstrap using two different navigation menus defined in our `module.config.php`. I created a new service factory to call the right nav and that is all working. Here is the code in my `layout.phtml`

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

  <?php

      echo $this->navigation('navigation')->menu($this->role)->setPartial(array('layout/partials/main-menu', 'default'));

      echo $this->navigation('right_navigation')->menu($this->role)->setPartial(array('layout/partials/secondary-menu','default'));

  ?>
</div>
```

It is calling the partials and navigation correctly, but it is placing the second navigation partial within the main navigation partial. Wondering how to separate the two or close off the first partial before calling the second.

Answer (score 0):

This was a closing tag error within the main-menu partial.